# Google table chart visible on button click

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to load a page with a google table chart as hidden and only show it after a button click.

If I start the page with the `table` not hidden I can toggle it, but if I start with the table hidden that isn't possible.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/ura0h5op/).

Swap the commented line to see it:

```
$("table").addClass( 'table-bordered table-condensed table-striped');
// $("table").addClass( 'table-bordered table-condensed table-striped hidden');
```

Comment: please explain it properly

Comment: Looking for a way to show a hidden table (google chart table) after a button click.

Comment: did you mean that when the page is load it should be hidden and it should show only after button click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code with this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
        $("#table").hide();
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
        $("#table").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
        $("#table").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS** to make the table initially hidden by setting its `display` to `none`.

```
#table {display:none;}
```

Then with jQuery [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) turn its `display` back to `block` when `#show` its clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
        $("#table").css('display', 'none');
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
        $("#table").css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

See an updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ura0h5op/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the hidden class when the show button is clicked:

`$("table").removeClass('hidden');`

(and reapply when hide is clicked).